# Strange mouse behavior after mouse event click

Tags: vb.net, mouseevent

I'm using Vb2010 and windows 7.
i'm trying to create a program that click on another process, but i'm having some trouble with the left and right click event.
In fact, when i right and then left click, the mouse will behave strangely: the left and right click will seems to swap, as left clicking will open the menu and right clicking will do nothing.
The only way to bring it back to normal is to physically right and then left click, but i need the program to do this automatically. Is there any fix or workaround? Thanks.

To recreate this problem you can create a form with a button1 in vb.net and paste this code (and then run the debug and click on the button), or you can download the already compiled program from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-HjVnWLaDDM1ZNcUZReTBBWVU/edit?usp=sharing).

```
Public Class Form1
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cbuttons As Integer, ByVal dwextrainfo As Integer)
Private Const mouseclickdown = 2
Private Const mouseclickup = 4
Private Const rightclickdown = 8
Private Const rightclickup = 10

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(650, 350)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(rightclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(rightclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(500, 200)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rightclickup` should have a value of `0x0010`(source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which is 10 in hexadecimal. In decimal, it's 16.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Integer, ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal cbuttons As Integer, ByVal dwextrainfo As Integer)
Private Const mouseclickdown = 2
Private Const mouseclickup = 4
Private Const rightclickdown = 8
Private Const rightclickup = 16

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(650, 350)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(rightclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(rightclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    Cursor.Position = New Point(500, 200)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
    mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was a stupid error but gave me so much trouble. Thank you again :)